# If my class implements Serializable, do I have to implement it in its subclasses?

Tags: java, serializable

If I have B extends A... and A implements Serializable, do I have to write "B implements Serializable" ?

I think no, but I would like confirmation...

also if I put serialization id in A... do I need to put one in B also ? should serialization id in A be protected (not private) ?

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but it would take less time to just try this than it took you to write this question.

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but this would be a very, very small website if that advice were heeded consistently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. Subclass need not be marked serializable explicitly.

And, marking id as `protected` will do (from compiler perspective).

But, as good practice every class should have it's own private `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to get rid of the yellow eclipse warning about no serial version id declared?

Comment: More robust way will be to define is as `private static final`

Comment: I still think it can be good to implement Serializable on the subclass for clarity. Just like how ArrayList implements List while also extending AbstractList which already implemented List.

Comment: You should use the `private` modifier on `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: Just to be clear... is it `serialVersionUID` or `serialVersionUid`? We have both here.

Answer (score 15):

You don't have to explicitly mark the derived as Serializable it will be inherited. However, the serialVersionUID from the parent, although inherited, will not be used by the serialization process. If you don't add a serialVersionUID to the child one will be generated.

See Below:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Class aClass = a.getClass();
        Class bClass = b.getClass();

        long aUid = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(aClass).getSerialVersionUID();
        long bUid = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(bClass).getSerialVersionUID();

        System.out.printf("serialVersionUID:\n");
        System.out.printf("b inherited from a: %d\n", b.serialVersionUID);
        System.out.printf("a used by serialization: %d\n",aUid);
        System.out.printf("b used by serialization: %d\n",bUid);
    }

}
```

Output:

> serialVersionUID:
>
> b inherited from a: 1
>
> a used by serialization: 1
>
> b used by serialization: -3675232183873847366

Answer (score 10):

In my agreement to @azodious answer, child class inherits serializable properties of parent class , but you will have to declare **serialVersionUID** explicitly.

From Java docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> It is also strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID
>   declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such
>   declarations apply only to the immediately declaring
>   class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members.

Answer (score 8):

Marking id as protected will suffice from a compiler perspective. However, in theory, the point of the  `serialVersionUID`  field on a `Serializable` class is to easily distinguish "versions" of the class when deserializing it -- to clearly denote when a given object can be deserialized into an instance of the provided class (if the `serialVersionUID`s are different, an exception is thrown).  If you want to be able to clearly track the versions and nature of an object, declare `serialVersionUID` on each subclass.

Comment: I think `serialVersionUIDs` is declared for JVM to identify the change in class. and JVM can get it from base class so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Well yeah, but my point really was, don't treat the serialVersionUID as an annoyance you're trying to get rid of. Learn why it's there and treat it appropriately.

Comment: Yes, but we can have two different classes with same `serialVersionUID`. if it was a simple class without extending any class explicitly, then it's should be mandatory.

Comment: my thinking was that the old files won't be compatible if I try to load it with new modified classes... so instead I wil never change the classes ever... (this is relatively simple classes .. I just have a list of them I'm serializing)... so just to be safe I put a bunch of string and int and boolean fields and called them "reserved1,2,etc." .. in the unlikely case I will need to attach more data to the class in the future... but so file will be exact same format still

Answer (score 3):

No, because B already implements it through its base class A. That's what inheritance is all about.

Answer (score 3):

A Java object is serializable if its class or any of its superclasses implements either the java.io.Serializable interface or its subinterface, java.io.Externalizable.

You can take a look at official documentation and find this there: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html